# Restore String Interpolation AFTER value replace

Tags: swift, string, string-interpolation

Given a str: `"My name is Gustavo"`, that was created with `"My name is \(foo.name)"`

Is it possible to get the string `"My name is \(foo.name)"` after the value was replaced?

---

In other words, is it possible to find out `"My name is \(foo.name)"`, having `"My name is Gustavo"`?

---

**Edit**: If I can get to `"My name is "`, a.k.a. the hard coded string from all strings that were build dynamically, that would be a solution.

Comment: Nope. Could you please explain why do you want that?

Comment: @Sulthan for replacing reasons, I need to compare the substring that was not created dynamically.

Comment: There are an infinite number of possible candidates. Of course, you could scan the complete source of your program (mind it must be the right version) (or even the executable and used shared libraries) to get candidates and then match them, just to narrow it down some. That's a lot of work though, and fragile.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, this is not possible. In fact, `"My name is \(foo.name)"` is not even included in the compiled code. Instead, Swift-5 compiler generates code equivalent to this:

```
let str = String(stringInterpolation: {
    var temp = String.StringInterpolation(literalCapacity: 11, interpolationCount: 1)
    temp.appendLiteral("My name is ")
    temp.appendInterpolation(foo.name)
    return temp
}())
```

[This article](http://ilya.puchka.me/swift5-string-interpolation/) contains details on how string interpolation is implemented in Swift-4 and Swift-5.